# Is being slightly overweight the only reason my cat doesn't eat sometimes?

Tags: cats, weight

My cat (Fluffy) is 12 year old Norwegian Forest Cat. He has been lately some days not eating. My wife worked more lately so he had less time with her. My wife took him to the vet and he checked his blood and physical and only found he was overweight- no signs of stress or kidney or liver problems. Before he was cutting to two meals then none and just lately he refused his dry cat food for only treats and wet cat food for one- other days he eats fine with his reduced quantity. Is there anything I should do? I work 6 day and so does my wife and we have a Year 2 elementary school son. I tempted him with tuna before when he didn't eat. My cat seems the same happiness level and activity- never been a big "play with humans" cat.  We were sad but not miserable.  My wife's parents lived upstairs and my cat goes upstairs often. My father-in-law got taken to hospital and died not long ago and his wife kept his corpse upstairs for a few days before the funeral home took him. Fluffy has been eating badly before seeing the vet and afterwards too but not all the time. Fluffy is an indoor cat with plenty of raised areas to hide in.

Comment: do I understand this right? The cat was normally eating, then the appointment with the vet, then the cat reduced eating? So the vet does not know about the changed behaviour?

Comment: How long has this been going on? Did this change in appetite come on very suddenly? How big a change in appetite is this compared to his normal appetite?

Comment: Previously his appetite tapered off for a month to nothing for one day before seeing the vet. Now it has happened again with him not eating for one. day. He was previously a bit irregular about when he eats which was close to his activity level but he got through three meals a day and some times was ravenous so we had to give an advance portion of the next meal. His current acitivity level is still good just not apparently highly active.  Fluffy is not losing his bodily condition.